# JS: Run a keyboard command from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to make a command that makes a webpage a bookmark. I read somewhere that we cannot do so from javascript because Google wants to make it more secure.

Is there any way to run a keyboard command from JavaScript. Like a javascript function that runs Ctrl+S or any such key combination.

Relatively new to JS, I am talking about this with respect to Chrome Extensions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot trigger a native action associated with a keyboard shortcut with an ordinary Chrome extension.

For your specific situation, adding a bookmark, use the [`chrome.bookmarks`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks) API. To save the web page, you can use XMLHttpRequest (HTML-only) or [`chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture#method-saveAsMHTML) (full page including all external resources).

If you want to trigger an action that is implemented in the web page, then you could use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to create synthetic events using one of the Event constructors (such as [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)) and fire the artificial event use [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) method.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look about this library https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap